# Importing a client certificate into the iPhone's keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, client-certificates, pkcs#12

I am writing an application that is communicating with a server which requires the client to authenticate itself using a client certificate. I need to extract the certificate from a .p12 file in the application bundle and add it to the application keychain.

I've been trying to figure out how to get it working from Apple's ["Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13), but to me it seems incomplete and does not specify how I add anything to the keychain(?).

I am quite lost and any help is appriciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13)" does contain sufficient information to extract certificate from a .p12 file.

- from listing 2-1 demonstrate how you can extract **SecIdentityRef**
- from listing 2-2 second line (// 1) shows how you can copy
  **SecCertificateRef** out of SecIdentityRef.

**example** loading p12 file, extract certificate, install to keychain.
(error handling and memory management was not included)

```
  NSString * password = @"Your-P12-File-Password";
  NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"Your-P12-File" ofType:@"p12"];

  // prepare password
  CFStringRef cfPassword = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL,
                                                     password.UTF8String,
                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  const void *keys[]   = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
  const void *values[] = { cfPassword };
  CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary
  = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1,
                                                  NULL, NULL);

  // prepare p12 file content
  NSData * fileContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
  CFDataRef cfDataOfFileContent = (__bridge CFDataRef)fileContent;

  // extract p12 file content into items (array)
  CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
  OSStatus status = errSecSuccess;
  status = SecPKCS12Import(cfDataOfFileContent,
                           optionsDictionary,
                           &items);
  // TODO: error handling on status

  // extract identity
  CFDictionaryRef yourIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
  const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
  tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(yourIdentityAndTrust,
                                      kSecImportItemIdentity);

  SecIdentityRef yourIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;


  // get certificate from identity
  SecCertificateRef yourCertificate = NULL;
  status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(yourIdentity, &yourCertificate);


  // at last, install certificate into keychain
  const void *keys2[]   = {    kSecValueRef,             kSecClass };
  const void *values2[] = { yourCertificate,  kSecClassCertificate };
  CFDictionaryRef dict
  = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys2, values2,
                                            2, NULL, NULL);
  status = SecItemAdd(dict, NULL);

  // TODO: error handling on status
```